# how do I know the price min and max price and last price by date , if the data obtained like this

Tags: mysql, sql

how do I know the price min and max price and last price by date , if the data obtained like this[image]

Comment: How do you define "last price"?  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "last" unless a column specifies the last row.

Comment: harga terakhir berdasarkan date example data 6/20/16 price 1606

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is named `table` and has columns `price` and `date`, to get the minimum or maximum price:

```
select min(price) from table

select max(price) from table
```

To get the most recent price by date:

```
select top 1 price from table order by date desc
```

Comment: for the last price ?

Comment: To get the oldest price by date, just `order by date asc`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "last" column is based on the first column, you can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select date(datecol), min(price), max(price),
       substring_index(group_concat(price order by date desc), ',', 1) as last_price
from t
group by date(datecol);
```

If `date` doesn't specify the ordering, then perhaps some other column does.